# Retrieve images from swift to typescript while using share extensions

Tags: ios, swift, typescript, image

I am trying to implement ShareExtensions in my ionic3 app.

I have followed the following procedure.

Build the app and open in Xcode. Then add Share Extension using **File -> New -> Target -> Share Extension.**

Then i have went through the following documentation

[Share Extension in ios](https://www.yudiz.com/share-extention-in-ios-app/)

Then in **ShareViewController.swift** file i have added these lines.

```
override func didSelectPost() {
        if let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem{
            for ele in item.attachments!{
                let itemProvider = ele

                if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.jpeg"){
                    NSLog("itemprovider: %@", itemProvider)
                    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.jpeg", options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) in

                        var imgData: String!

                        if let img = item as? UIImage{
                            imgData = img.pngData()?.base64EncodedString(options: <#T##Data.Base64EncodingOptions#>)
                        }

                        let dict: [String : Any] = ["imgData" :  imgData, "name" : self.contentText]
                        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard

                        userDefault.set(dict, forKey: "img")
                        userDefault.synchronize()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)

    }
```

Share view Controller file is located in

> ./platforms/ios/shareItems/ShareViewController.swift

Now the images what i have selected in the gallery should be sent to my app. And i need to retrieve it in one of my typescript page say login.ts which is located in.

> .src/pages/login/login.ts

I need to pass the base64encoded images to my login page, How to write the functions for it so that i can retrieve the images.

Any hep appreciated.

.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to get images and text details from `UserDefaults` using the following code.

```
let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefault.addSuite(named: "group.yudiz.shareKitDemo")

        if let dict = userDefault.value(forKey: "img") as? NSDictionary{

            let data = dict.value(forKey: "imgData") as! Data
            let str = dict.value(forKey: "name") as! String

            self.imgView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.lblText.text = str

            userDefault.removeObject(forKey: "img")
            userDefault.synchronize()
        }
```

And now if you want to pass image as base64encoded then use the following function.

```
//convert the image to Data first
let imageData = image.pngData()!
// convert the Data to base64 encoding    
let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

again decode base64string to convert into an image by the following code.

```
let dataDecoded:Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!
```